# How to Import Multiple csv files into a MySQL Database using batch script

Tags: batch-file, mysql-workbench

I have multiple csv file every month to be imported to mySQL table. Assuming the database called test and table named called business. I have saved the all csv file and the bat file (please refer coding below) in the folder called C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads.

The moment I double click the bat file to run, and check table "business" in mySQL, nothing is imported. If there is anyone can help with me to see where goes wrong please?

Many thanks in advance.

Bat File Content:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
  set old=%%~dpnxf
  set new=!old:\=\\!
  mysql -e "load data local infile '"!new!"' IGNORE into table test.business  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','" -u root
  echo %%~nxf DONE
)
```

Content in the CSV file (2 columns, one name and ID)
File 1

```
Name,ID
aaa,111
bbb,222
```

File 2

```
Name,ID
ccc,333
ddd,444
```

Comment: Right-click on your shortcut, select "properties" and set "Start in" to your data directory `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads` otherwise the batch will run in whatever directory has been set in "start in", likely find no `*.csv` there, so exit. You'd need to add a `pause` line at the end of your posted code to see the `echo`ed messages. I'm assuming your `mysql` line is valid. Perhaps you should `echo` that line to make sure.

Comment: Because you are running the batch file by double-clicking it, prepend the first line with `@`, replace ```enabledelayedexpansion``` with ```enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion```, remove these lines, ```set old=%%~dpnxf``` and ```set new=!old:\=\\!```, and change ```!new!``` to ```%cd:\=\\%\\%%f```.

Comment: Hihi thank you for the reply!
I have changed the coding as such : 

@echo off
setlocal enableextension disabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN ("*.csv") DO (
  mysql -e "load data local infile "cd:\=\\%\\%%f" IGNORE into table text.business  COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','" -u root -p
  echo %%~nxf DONE
)

timeout /t 30 /nobreak

however, it shows the following error message
Invalid parameter to SETLOCAL Command
Error at line 1: Unknown command '\='